# Open MS Word document with webdav and asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word, webdav

I'm stucked when trying to handle MS Word document by clicking link on ASP .NET MVC 4 website which use WebDav protocol.
MS Word document should be on local folder, not in same or sub folder of ASP .NET MVC project folder.
I just want to open MS Word document, edit then save (upload to WebDav server)

I'm new to WebDav and find little tutorial or support for webdav on MVC.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen clicking a link just results in a normal download via GET, and then the downloaded file is opened and edited.

To open the file in an editor from its original location (using webdav) you need to use an extension to make a call to the editing program. On internet explorer you can use the sharepoint dll with ActiveX code:

```
Set EditDocumentButton = CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3")
strDocument = 'http://localhost:8080' + strDocument; 
EditDocumentButton.EditDocument(strDocument)
```

[Using Office Web Apps, Can you open a document via webdav?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696309/using-office-web-apps-can-you-open-a-document-via-webdav)

I have heard that similar capabilities are available in Chrome and Firefox, but dont have details.